# For which $y \in \mathbb{R}$ does $R(y) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty(\frac{8y}{16+y^2})^n$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

**My attempt:**

The first thing I notice is that $R(y)$ is a geometric series that converges,
if $|\frac{8y}{16+y^2}| < 1$.

[image]

**Case 1: $\frac{8y}{16+y^2} \ge 0$**

$\frac{8y}{16+y^2} < 1\Leftrightarrow 8y < 16+ y^2 \Leftrightarrow 0 < y^2 - 8y +16$

$y_{1} < -(\frac{-8}{2}) \pm \sqrt{(\frac{-8}{2})^2-16}$

$y_1 < 4-\sqrt{16 -16} = 4$

**Case 2: $\frac{8y}{16+y^2} < 0$**

$\frac{-8y}{16+y^2} < 1\Leftrightarrow -8y < 16+ y^2 \Leftrightarrow 0 < y^2 + 8y +16$

$y_{2} < -(\frac{8}{2}) \pm \sqrt{(\frac{-8}{2})^2-16}$

$y_2 < -4\sqrt{16 -16} = -4$

$\mathbb{L} = \{(-\infty,-4) \cup(4,+\infty) \}$

**(1)** I don't know how to handle $\pm 3, \pm 2, \pm 1 $ and $0$ apart from trying it out (which would take too much time).

**(2)** Wolfram alpha has different results https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7C(8y)%2F(16%2By%5E2)%7C+%3C+1 and I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned $R(y)$ converges if and only if $|\frac{8y}{y^2+16}|<1$. Since this is equivalent to $-1<\frac{8y}{y^2+16}<1$ and $y^2+16>0$, we have $(y-4)^2>0$ and $(y+4)^2>0$, which implies that $R(y)$ converges for all $y\neq4, -4$.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case we are looking for $y\ge 0$ such that $0<y^2-8y+16.$ You went to the quadradic formula and somehow turned it into an inequality. That inequality is not correct. You can see that by noting $8y/(y^2+16)\to 0$ as $y\to \infty.$ Thus we will have $8y/(y^2+16)<1$ for large $y.$

An easy solution here is to note $|8y/(y^2+16)|$ is an even function. Thus $y$ will make the expression less than $1$ iff $-y$ does the same. So we can concentrate on $y\ge 0.$

Now if $y\ge 0,$ then $8y/(y^2+16)<1$ iff $0<y^2-8y +16.$ Note that $y^2-8y +16= (y-4)^2.$ That will be positive iff $y\ne 4.$ So the set of nonnegative $y$'s that work is $[0,\infty)\setminus\{4\}.$ By the remarks above, it follows that the full solution set is $\mathbb R \setminus\{-4,4\}.$

Answer (score 1):

Actually, $\left\lvert\frac{8y}{y^2+16}\right\rvert < 1$ holds for all $y \notin \{-4, 4\}$. We can multiply both sides of the inequation by $\lvert y^2+16\rvert$, which is always positive.

$$\left\lvert\frac{8y}{y^2+16}\right\rvert < 1$$
$$\iff \lvert8y\rvert < \lvert y^2+16\rvert = y^2 + 16$$
$$\iff -y^2 - 16 < 8y < y^2 + 16$$
$$\iff \left\{\begin{aligned}
&y^2 -8y + 16 > 0 && \\
&y^2 +8y + 16 > 0  &&
\end{aligned}\right.
$$
$$\iff \left\{\begin{aligned}
&(y - 4)^2 > 0 && \\
&(y + 4)^2 > 0  &&
\end{aligned}\right.
$$
$$\iff \left\{\begin{aligned}
&y \ne 4 && \\
&y \ne -4 &&
\end{aligned}\right.
$$

So, your series converges if and only if $y \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{-4, 4\}$.

In Wolfram Alpha try querying "|(8y)/(16+y^2)| < 1 reals", and it will output the same result.

Answer (score 1):

$|\frac{8y}{y^2+16}| < 1$ is equivalent to $(|y|-4)^2>0$ which is true for $y\in \mathbb R - \{-4,4\}$.